# Can the .NET JIT compiler inline methods that are decorated with attributes?

Tags: c#, .net

If there is an attribute (any attribute),there is probably a reason, so in theory, it shouldn't be inlined but it's just a guess.
Do I have to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` if I want to suggest I don't want Inlining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in general? sure; however, both the compiler and JIT are free to pay special attention to anything in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`, and apply special rules (well, *technically* they can pay special attention to anything at all, but the relevant types *tend* to be there; counter-examples would be `[Obsolete]` and `[Serializable]`, which are not in that namespace but which have special rules). `[MethodImpl(...)]` is one of those attributes with special rules for the JIT.

Attributes in the general sense, however; make no real difference.

Yes, `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` requests that the JIT should not inline this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing some performance analysis based on Attributes and some things look off, possibly because certain methods are inlined. I'll try adding "MethodImpl"